# Telerik radgird show column sum in footer in rad grid depend on other column

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

i just want to sum a column and show in footer but problem is that column sum is depend on other column value. 
Example
in my grid i have two column 
one for price and second for currency code

```
Price   CurrencyCode   
100      Eur
54       GBP
65       GBP
89       USD
41       EUR
```

i wanted to sum a price according to currency code
show sum in footer Like this
Eur: 141
GBP: 119
USD: 89
how to do this help me..
thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sumEur = yourtable.compute("sum(Price)",CurrencyCode='GBP');
var sumGBP = yourtable.compute("sum(Price)",CurrencyCode='EUR');
var sumUSD = yourtable.compute("sum(Price)",CurrencyCode='USD');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to generate this text in your code behind. You can use the DataBound event of the grid if you want access to the data, although I would probably calculate this from the datasource directly.
Using linq you can easily get sums like:

```
var sumEur = datasource.Where(i => i.CurrencyCode == "EUR").Sum(i => i.Price);
var sumUsd = datasource.Where(i => i.CurrencyCode == "USD").Sum(i => i.Price);
etc.
```

and then:

```
string total = String.Format("Eur: {0} GBP: {1} USD {2}", sumEur, sumGbp, sumUsd);
```

And then just place the total string in your page how and where you want it.